# How to use dynamically added hidden input field to form in controller action in asp.net mvc 3?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have tried in following way .This is fine that adds the hidden input to the form    dynamically .But how do that hidden input field is used in controller action so that i will do further work that is rendering dynamically added image in browser.

JQuery Append method :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       var alts = "";
       var n = 65;

       $(document).ready(function () {
           $(function () {
               $("#selectable_images img").click(function () {
                   var $this = $(this);
                   //                      alts = $(this).attr("alt");
                   // alert(alts);
                   if ($this.hasClass('selected')) {
                       $("#" + this.rel).attr('checked', false);
                       $this.removeClass('selected');
                       // $("#postform").remove("");
                       //$("input[type='hidden']").remove();

                       //$('input[type="hidden"][value="' + alts + '"]').remove();
                       alts = $(this).attr("alt");

                       var ref = "#";
                       ref += alts.toString();
                       alert(ref);
                       $(ref).remove();

                   } else {
                       $("#" + this.rel).attr('checked', true);
                       $this.addClass('selected');
                       alts = $(this).attr("alt");
                       alert(alts);
                       charPos++;

                       $("#postform").append("<input type='hidden' id='" + alts.toString() + "' value='" + n.toString() + "'/>");
                       n++;
                   }
               })
           })
       });
</script>
```

image tag:

```
<div class="selected" id="selectable_images">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img src="../../Images/wi0096-48.gif"  alt="Image1" class="conversation_img"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <img src="../../Images/down.png"  alt ="image1"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <img src="../../Images/wi0054-48.gif" alt="Image2" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <img src="../../Images/Photo-icon.png" alt="image3" />
            </td>

</div>
```

form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("MapIcon","test", FormMethod.Post,new { id = "postform" }))
{   
    <input type="submit" value="Match"/>
}
```

Comment: In the "image tag" section: You have not closed your `table` element properly: `</table>`

Answer (score 2):

You need to give your hidden `input` a `name` attribute value. As the `name` attribute is what is used to identify form post values on the server side.

So assuming you give it a value (when you create it with javascript) like: `name="myHiddenInput"`

You can then access that from within your controller action using the following:

```
string myHiddenInput = Request.Form["myHiddenInput"];
```

Comment: it is ony for a single image .I have bunch of images .How do that ?

Comment: @user2663526: If you have multiple hidden inputs, then use a different `name` for each. perhaps use a counter, e.g. `name1`, `name2`...etc. In your controller you can loop from 1 until you find a null form entry (i.e. a number greater than is available)

Comment: is it possible to get the id of each image in controller action like value of image

Comment: @user2663526: No, you can only access the value of the field. You would have to store the ID in some other field if you wanted to pass that over to the server

Comment: how can i extract id of these hidden field using jquery methods

Comment: @user2663526: You have already asked that question and got an answer for it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18140885/how-to-extract-id-elments-from-hidden-filed-using-jquery