# How to extract id elments from hidden filed using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following form. From this i want `id` of each hidden field. How to do that. Is it possible to remove hidden element using `id` of hidden elements by jquery Remove methods

**Form:**

```
<form id="postform" method="post" action="/test/MapIcon">
    <input type="submit" value="Match">
    <input id="65" type="hidden" name="image" value="../../Images/wi0096-48.gif">
    <input id="66" type="hidden" name="image" value="../../Images/down.png">
    <input id="67" type="hidden" name="image" value="../../Images/wi0054-48.gif">
</form>
```

I have tried in this way: This jquery methods

```
var alts = $(this).attr("id");
var   alts = $(this).attr('id');
var   alts = jQuery(this).attr("id");
var ref = "#";
ref += alts.toString();
alert(ref);//getting # value only
```

I have tried but getting # value only .So please give me some idea .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var hiddenIds = [];
$('input:hidden').each( function() {
   hiddenIds.push($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

And output is `hiddenIds` array.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear, still I think the below will solve the first question

To get ids of hidden element

```
// hiddenIds will be an array of the element id
var hiddenIds = $('#postform input:hidden').map(function(){
    return this.id
}).get();
```